# symbols in text files are wrongly written in xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a text file with special symbols like £,€  I want to write it to xml file while writing these symbol it is written as Question mark.

Below is my code:

```
String[] data = File.ReadAllLines("SpecialSymbols.TXT");
XElement root = new XElement("root",
         from item in data
         select new XElement("Line", item));
root.Save("XmlFile.Xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

Encoding in xml must be encoding="utf-8" then these symbols are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Read lines from file with Encoding

```
String[] data = File.ReadAllLines("SpecialSymbols.TXT",Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: You can see [from the implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,990) that this will make no difference. I'd agree that this looks like an encoding problem, however.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `XDocument` not and `XElement` and specify the xml encoding
Like so...

```
string[] data = File.ReadAllLines("SpecialSymbols.TXT");
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("root",
        from item in data
        select new XElement("Line", item))
    );
xDoc.Save("XmlFile.Xml");
```